# I do not understand why BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray is returning null

Tags: java, android, base64, bitmapfactory

I have encoded a bitmap into a string Base64 which I stored in mysql database. I then retrieved this information and I'm trying to reconstruct a bitmap from it.

The value of the blob is not null and is in base64. Well, it does seem in base64. When I do this

```
//This has the encoded string 
String encodedString = intervention.getUser_sign()

byte[] decodedUserString = Base64.decode(intervention.getUser_sign(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
Bitmap decoded_user_sign = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedUserString, 0, decodedUserString.length);
user_sign.setImageBitmap(decoded_user_sign);
```

decoded_user_sign is 'null'.

In the logcat, the only information I have is:

```
DEBUG/skia(31358): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
```

This is the encoded code:

```
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,50,baos);
        byte[] bytes=baos.toByteArray();
        String base64Image = Base64.encodeToString(bytes,Base64.NO_WRAP);
```

Can someone explain to me what am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Can you post the code for the "encode" side ?

Comment: @ben75, I added the encoded code in the question

Comment: I have found the answer. It took me several hours to figure it out...it was so stupid. I was encoding an already encoded variable...very sorry to have disturbed you. Thanks for your help!